# MySQL/PHP: how to distinguish between multiple users in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a simple web app to let user input data as they walk around in a warehouse looking up products.

The database is a very simple one I created for the sole purpose of gathering some product data. They start the process by entering the location they are at the warehouse. There are multiple users, and I did not implement a login feature; the application is accessible by anyone on the local network.

I want to keep track of the location IDs that the users input, but I want to be able to distinguish data input by different users.

I need an identifier that will allow me to distinguish one user from another. It can even be different for the same user every time he connects to the DB or uses a different computer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. They were all useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the [session id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) I guess, but it's not very identifiable to a specific user.

It would however allow you to identify which actions were done in the same session.

Just remember to start your session first:

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way: http://php.net/session_id

And don't forget to init session: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of a unique session ID along with setting a unique User ID in the Session as well so both can be recorded. I do something similar with an application we use.

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['UserID']  == ? <---- Create you variable
```

You can read more here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Keeping track of sessions will also allow you to monitor active sessions, record active sessions in database, implement some basic timeout functionality if they are not active for a period of time, etc...